# Fb-Prophet, Apache Spark in Colab and AWS SageMaker/ Lambda

Tags: apache-spark, google-colaboratory, amazon-sagemaker, facebook-prophet

I am using `Google-Colab` for creating a model by using FbProphet and i am try to use Apache Spark in the `Google-Colab` itself. Now can i upload this `Google-colab` notebook in `aws Sagemaker/Lambda` for free `(without charge for Apache Spark and only charge for AWS SageMaker)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, You can upload the notebook without any issue into SageMaker. Few things to keep in mind

1. If you are using the pyspark library in colab and running spark locally,  you should be able to do the same by installing necessary pyspark libs in Sagemaker studio kernels. Here you will only pay for the underlying compute for the notebook instance. If you are experimenting then I would recommend you to use https://studiolab.sagemaker.aws/ to create a free account and try things out.
2. If you had a separate spark cluster setup then you may need a similar setup in AWS using EMR so that you can connect to the cluster to execute the job.